# Incoming/Outgoing seperation for VPN (hacker protection only)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, networking, openvpn

So I have looked at existing questions and answers, and nothing matches.

Very simply all I want is inbound connections to pass through the vpn, and outbound connections to bypass the vpn altogether.  I use openvpn, how can this be achieved?

Why.  Because the hacker protection is essential and a little cost whereas the cost of systemwide outbound privacy is too high.
Original speed: 75 MBPS
VPN: 6 MBPS
Apt or Git post VPN: 0.5 MBS

Hence pass all inbound traffic through the VPN, pass all outbound traffic outside of the vpn.  How can it be done if I use OpenVPN and debian?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how to best use this site. To get to your question, could you please [edit it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/545553/edit) to include a more clear example of your goals? What exactly do you want to accomplish and what kind of information should an acceptable answer include? I think what you are looking for is a proxy/reverse-proxy not a vpn. Thank you.

Comment: this should probably be posted to the Information Security site.

Answer (score 0):

VPNs work by creating a network "layer" atop a pyhsical network, thus the "virtual" distinction.  You still have an incoming IP address on the private end - and indeed you must, as the physical connectivity underlies the virtual connection.

The VPN provides some degree of anonymity because by the time the remote server sees the incoming IP, it's the VPN's IP and not your own.   Traffic to the VPN service from your IP is visible, but the entire payload is encrypted so all an observer can say is that the traffic is going to the vpn service, not what's going to pop out the other side.

This is distinct from security.  The VPN service doesn't inherently add any sort of packet filtering or ingress protection.  It merely masks your IP from *your* end and masquerades as the source of the traffic from the perspective of the final destination.

Now let's talk about incoming traffic.  There's really two kinds - *responses* to locally originating traffic such as webserver response when you visit a webpage, and *new* connections that were established remotely and , ostensibly, connect to a service your system offers.

Existing connections can hypothetically be compromised.  Typically this would be a man-in-the-middle situation where a nefarious actor would be able to inject arbitrary data into request, response, or both.  In the real world your protection against this is theoretically assured by HTTPS, ssh host key verification, etc.  If you don't trust them, better not user the internet at all, because the VPN doesn't change this, it just moves the MiTM window from "outside your computer" to "outside the VPN".    So the VPN isn't going to address this inherently.

But there's more. Connections that were established through the VPN will be associated with the outgoing VPN address, not your local address.  In essence, the whole point of the VPN is that the final destination for your traffic does not see your locally originating IP, right?  So how exactly is the final destination going to know to send its response directly to you, bypassing the VPN?

Even if there *were* such way to request responses to an IP other than the requesting IP, it probably wouldn't be commonly supported, because any service that supported it would be open to reflection attacks; it has no way of verifying the "original" IP and so you could attack any IP by simply making inexpensive requests with big, expensive responses and tell them to respond to that IP.  The attacked IP will discard all the traffic, but it could still cause a denial of service by overwhelming the IP with illegitimate traffic.

And TCP doesn't work that way.  You can't "simply" make a connection from address A and have the responses go to address B.

So I've convinced myself that a VPN:

- doesn't inherently provide any protection from the "hackers" you fear
- doesn't have any way to support, and probably wouldn't support, responses to an IP that wasn't the requesting IP.

Ok, new connections are a lot easier.  If you manage your own VPN you can probably set it up to forward incoming connections to your local machine . But it doesn't add any security that you couldn't add locally in terms of firewall and ingress protection.  A VPN doesn't give you that, as we described.  Or you can accept incoming connections without the VPN (you'd have to have a partial route to the VPN in this case, and it's much more common to send *all* traffic through the VPN, but it's certainly within openVPNs capabilities to route only some traffic over the VPN).  Either way, the VPN isn't inherently doing any sort of filtering of the traffic.  Those nefarious parties, if they're already targeting the connection, just attack on the other side of the vpn.

The easiest way to protect offered services on a system is to turn them off.  Run them somewhere else on a dedicated host or, if you actually need to offer this service to the internet, you'll have to secure your services somehow.  If you're worried about hackers, listening on any port is the most likely way they'd access your system, and the easiest way to elude that is to simply not allow new connections into your system, only traffic associated with connections originating on the system .

But again, that's completely irrespective of the VPN.  You could do those things on the VPN server or on your own Server.

My advice to you?  Focus on good security practices on your workstation and, unless *partial online anonymity* is a serious goal of yours, just ditch the vpn.  It doesn't do what you think it does.  I hope after reading this it's clear why.

Comment: My goal breaks protocol; right.  In the end, it would seem there is only 3 ways to hack a system.  An existing backdoor i.e., especially in the kernel, piggybacking an established TCP connection, to send packets that make it through to host computer/security.  So what a clever person might do is only allow outgoing udp, and drop all incoming connections, and maybe only allow Tor TCP but in virtual machine.  To deal with the backdoor, all private work is to be in a virtual machine though unfortunately screen capture will be possible especially with Xorg.  So your right, screw the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Just serve whatever services you have on the interface created by the **VPN server**, which you should run at this machine. Except, you will have the only VPN service available at your public IP. This will not affect your outgoing connections. You may also disallow any traffic coming from the VPN and trying to get out elsewhere, so tunnelling through this server.